How to run android service from android worker when android application closed and got broadcast message?
My react-native android app is available for download from multiple app stores.
I need to make it so that certain push notifications are sent only to instances of the app downloaded from certain app stores. But since an app downloaded from one app store can be updated from another app store, I need to notify the server of this fact.
To do this, I listen for the broadcast message and run my code.
Here is my code
package com.wbdigitalmobile;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;

public class PackageReplacedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String TAG = "PackageReplacedReceiver";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");

    OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PackageReplacedWorker.class).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request);
  }
}

package com.wbdigitalmobile;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;

public class PackageReplacedWorker extends Worker {
  private static final String TAG = "PackageReplacedWorker";
  private final Context context;

  public PackageReplacedWorker (Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams ) {
    super ( context, workerParams );
    this.context = context;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public Result doWork () {
    Log.d(TAG, "doWork");

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this.context, PushNotificationTokenUpdateService.class);

    this.context.startService(serviceIntent);
    HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(this.context);

    return Result.success ();
  }
}


package com.wbdigitalmobile;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class PushNotificationTokenUpdateService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
  private static final String TAG = "PushNotificationTokenUpdateService";
  public static final int SERVICE_ID = 800000;
  private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "PushNotificationTokenUpdateService";

  private Notification buildNotification() {
    final String taskTitle = "taskTitle";
    final String taskDesc = "taskDesc";

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
      .setContentTitle(taskTitle)
      .setContentText(taskDesc);

    return builder.build();
  }

  private void createNotificationChannel() {
    final int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;

    final NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "taskTitle", importance);

    channel.setDescription("taskDesc");

    final NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannel();

    startForeground(SERVICE_ID, buildNotification());
  }

  @Override
  protected @Nullable HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getTaskConfig");

    return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
      "PushNotificationTokenUpdateService",
      Arguments.createMap(),
      5000,
      true
    );
  }
}

As you can see, I am trying to run React-native Headless JS task, but the foreground task can't be run from Worker when application closed.
How can I run react-native headlessjs task from Worker when my application is closed?

I have a new method :Android variants.
in buidl.gradle :
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField('String', 'type_google', '"googlePlayStore"')
        buildConfigField('String', 'type_web', '"myWeb"')
    }

    buildTypes {
        apptype1{
            ...
            buildConfigField('String', 'type', '"googlePlayStore"')
        }
        apptype2{
            ...
            buildConfigField('String', 'type', '"myWeb"')
        }
    }
}

than,You can notify server when app open.also not display push data.
if(BuildConfig.type.equals(BuildConfig.type_google)){
    // TODO do some thing
}

when ready release app,you can select build apptype1 or apptype2 and build all.
The only difference between the two apps is this variable(BuildConfig.type)


2024-8-13

if  get push When you use websocket or http ,write code in callback function.
if when you use gms(FCM),write code in your FirebaseMessagingService

How to do that even if app was not opened by user after updating?

What are you push method? webosokcet(Http) or gms(FCM)?
You can't get push when you use websocket.
You can change id of gms to get different push when use gms.

example : {"target":"googlePlayStore","msg":"hello word"}
